# Do I have to create a directive to use $asyncValidators

Tags: angularjs

I created this code:

```
         <input class="inputField"
                       id="registerUserName"
                       name="registerUserName"
                       ng-model="aus.registerUserName"
                       ng-model.$asyncvalidators.unique="aus.isUsernameAvailable";
                       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }"
                       ng-minlength="5"
                       ng-required="true"
                       placeholder="Username"
                       type="text"
                       value="" />


isUsernameAvailable = function {
    return true;
}
```

But it seems my validator is not getting called. All the examples I see create a directive for the asyncvalidators. Is it possible to do it without creating a directive like I tried?

Comment: I will look at the documentation now (I haven't used asyncvalidators yet), but this is definitely wrong as you can't use `.` in html like you have...

Comment: I did see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272416/call-async-service-in-angularjs-custom-validation-directive   It talks about how to do it and I don't see any directive in the answer.  However I am not sure how to apply this example.

Comment: In the answer you linked `username-verify` is a directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do have to create a directive. The code example that you have shown is sort of attempting to use html in javascript.

You need to access the `ng-model` controller on the element that you want to validate, which (as far as I know) you can only do by creating another directive and using `require` in the directive definition object.

You could also make a directive that accepts an expression to add to the `asyncvalidators` a bit like what you are doing there.

It would look something like this: (not tested, probably not working code!)

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('useAsyncValidators', function (){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    // you need this line to access ngModel controller (4th arg to link)
    require: 'ngModel',

    link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
      // assume we pass an object with validatorname: validatorFunction fields.
      validators = scope.$eval( attributes.useAsyncValidators );
      for(var validator in validators) {
        // check the validator is a function
        if typeof validators[validator] === "function"
          // set validator on ngModelController
          ngModel.$asyncValidators[validator] = validators[validator];
      }
    }
}

// Which you could then use with the following:
.controller('validateTestController', function ($scope, $timeout) {

  delayedValidator = function () {
    return $timeout(true, 1000);
  };

  alwaysTrue = function () {
    return true;
  };

  $scope.validators = {
    isNameAvailable: alwaysTrue,
    isEmailAvailable: delayedValidator
  }
});
```

Then use the following markup:

```
<form ng-controller="validateTestController">
  <input class="inputField"
         ng-model="whatever"
         use-async-validators="validators" />
</form>
```

etc.

This would result in validating the field with a validator called `isNameAvailable` using the `alwaysTrue` function, and another on the same field with `isEmailAvailable` using `delayedValidator`.

Obivously these validator functions don't make sense really, but hopefully you can see that it's only a few lines of code to make a generic directive that does what you're trying to do in your markup.