# Angularjs form validation for existing value does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

I have problem understanding why my directive, which checks form validation, does not work.

My form definition:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
        <input type="text" 
            name="groupName" 
            ng-model="group[0].name"  
            groupname="group[0].name"
            ng-minlength="1" 
            ng-required="true"
            ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" />
        <div ng-if="myForm.groupName.$pending.credentialNameExists">checking....</div>
        <div ng-if="myForm.groupName.$error.credentialNameExists">group name exists already</div>
    </form>
</body>
```

My angularjs controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.group = [
    {
      name: 'Group1'
    }  
  ];
});
```

Form validation directive:

```
app.directive('credentialNameDirective', function(modalService,$timeout,$q){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            otherModelValue: "=groupname"
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$asyncValidators.credentialNameExists = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                    // consider empty model valid
                    return $q.when();
                }

                var def = $q.defer();
                if ((scope.otherModelValue !== undefined &&
                      scope.otherModelValue === modelValue ) ) {
                    def.resolve();
                    return def.promise;
                }

                def.reject();
                return def.promise;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

I need to provide the form's model data via $scope.group[i].name.
Validation via directive is not triggering after onblur action. How can I achieve that event will fire directive?

Is there any way that I can make this work?

I prepared plunker example with my problem: [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/D9CHhVvgvhSdxA6CPj9M?p=preview)

Thanks

Comment: you dont seem to be using your directive anywhere

Comment: @haxxxton can you tell me have can I use it?

Comment: do you actually need to use `async` here? will you be calling off to an external service to validate your data, or is this all happening locally?

Comment: I'm going to call external service to check if group with that name already exists.

Comment: Have a look at this solution then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26298465/648350